# Debugging CakeEmail, msg sent but not received

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, email

I'm using CakePHP 2.1.1 and trying to send a simple email with form data. This is the code I have in my controller:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

try {
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array('support@pcn.com' => 'PC')); 
    $Email->to('me@gmail.com');
    $Email->subject('New Registration');
    if ( $Email->send(serialize($formData)) ) 
        $this->set('email', 'Success');
    else 
        $this->set('email', 'Failure without Exception');
} 
catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $this->set('email', 'Failure with Exception );
}
```

When I print out the value of 'email' in my view, it is always 'Success', but I never receive the email (ive checked the spam folder). There are no email related issues in the error log. How do I debug this problem and get the email to send properly?

Comment: are you sending via SMTP? or from pcn.com domain?

Comment: either would be fine, this code is coming from the basic usage instructions

Comment: the basic php mailer is only working if your environment is setup propery. So I advice you to use SMTP (should also be outlined there somewhere). This always works regardless of the current setup (either locally or on the production server).

Comment: Yes, the SMTP setup works okay.